# Number of columns in "full-width" PSD design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have one PSD design, which 1980px (full-width), and I need to convert it to HTML, using Bootstrap 3.

I do know that Bootstrap 3 has an option to fluid grids, but my question is **how can I count number of columns needed for each section on website? **

If this is that, 1980px design:

[image]

How can I know how many columns to set for the black, red, and blue section?

Comment: It depends on how many columns you have in total. Usually when I receive a psd file, columns are visible. The graphic designer leaves the guides he used in the file. Try to set the guides to visible with cmd+;

Comment: Always **Mobile First**  that's the basic .... do you have the design for mobile also?  The number of columns can be just a proportion

Comment: Measure the width of each column, in pixels or whatever unit, and you can use the proportion between them to determine the number of columns.

Comment: @JonasGrumann
He did not left guides... :(

Comment: @DanielPinzon
No, I do not have design for mobile... :-(

Comment: @Drown
Aha, ok! It is dummy question, but does it mean that PSD to Bootstrap 3 cannot be pixel perfect?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an overlay of columns on your example:

[image]

So in this case, your html would look something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>Black Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>Red Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p>Blue Column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

See [**this working demo**](http://www.bootply.com/sDsbIArBER)

Comment: I understand this, but this is resized to 1170px. What will be if I have this example, when I have real 1980px.
What will be in this situation?
http://i.imgur.com/4Y8EwqY.jpg

Comment: Those column widths are percentages of the container--the math would follow that. Like ( (totalWidth / 12) * column count )