# How to check number of columns in a row from PSD in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to check number of columns in a row from PSD in Bootstrap?
I have tried and searched it a lot but I couldn't find it so please help....

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap we have 12 column you can check bootstrap documentation. you can modify columns depend on requirement

Comment: No I want to check the column size like col-lg-?,col-sm-?   in PSD. How to measure or check this?

Comment: 1 column / 12 grid-columns = 8.33% * 1170px = 97.5px
2 columns / 12 grid-columns = 16.67% * 1170px = 195px
3 columns / 12 grid-columns = 25% * 1170px = 292.5px

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633735/number-of-columns-in-full-width-psd-design